# Jackson Mixins with Kotlin

Tags: android, json, jackson, kotlin

I'm trying to use Jackson mixins to ignore a property of an external Kotlin data class, but so far, it's not working for me.

This is my SimpleModule extension:

```
class BarModule : SimpleModule() {
    override fun setupModule(context: SetupContext?) {
        context?.setMixInAnnotations(Bar::class.java, BarMixin::class.java)
    }
}
```

And this is my mixin:

```
abstract class BarMixin {
    @JsonIgnore val totalValue: Double = 0.0
}
```

I originally tried @JsonIgnore val totalValue: Double, but it wouldn't accept that.

This is my class:

```
data class Bar(
        val a: String,
        val b: Boolean = false,
        val c: Boolean = false,
        val d: Array<Block>
) {
    val totalValue: Double by lazy {
        d.sumByDouble { it.value }
    }
}
```

This is how I create my mapper:

```
private val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule()).registerModule(BarModule())
```

When running, it crashes with the error: Unable to start activity: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "totalValue", not marked as ignorable

Answer (score 6):

Try putting the annotation on the constructor of your MixIn, like:

```
abstract class BarMixin (
    @JsonIgnore val totalValue: Double = 0.0
)
```

(notice the `()` instead of `{}`)

Comment: Caveat: the constructor of your mixin has to match the constructor of your target class exactly: parameter names, order, and types. I discovered this after a long session in a debugger, where I discovered that the constructors are matched, at the very least, by number of arguments.